# No Connection between SP2013 and Workflow manger

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow, powershell

Goal:
Install Workflow manager in order to use SharePoint 2013 workflow.

Problem:
When I try registrating between SP2013 och WorkFlow manager based on the code:

```
 Give this command "Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://xxxx" -WorkflowHostUri "http://xxxx:12291" - AllowOAuthHttp
```

I retrieve an error message:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService : Unable to connect to the remote service at http://sharepoint01.com:12291/SharePoint/. See InnerException for more
 details. Client ActivityId : ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4.
At line:2 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://sharepoint01/" -WorkflowHostUri "http ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:RegisterSPWorkflowService) [Register-SPWorkflowService], Workfl 
   owEndpointNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService
```

> I was trying a lot to solve this case but I still don't know what to
>   do?

Information:
- Using SharePOint 2013 in my WMware Player

- http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Configuring-SharePoint-2013-to-support-workflow-Management-Service.aspx#.UwS0C4U6tnE

-Error message from C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

```
Process                     Area                    Category                        Message     Correlation
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  Entering BeginProcessing Method of Register-SPWorkflowService.  ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Register-SPWorkflowService.   ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  Entering ProcessRecord Method of Register-SPWorkflowService.    ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   Topology                    SecurityTokenServiceSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustChannelContract' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:a27554c4-0068-48ba-88b7-66622d90ac56' ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
w3wp.exe (0x1B88)           SharePoint Foundation   Topology                    SecurityTokenServiceReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://sharepoint01.adventureworks.local:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:a27554c4-0068-48ba-88b7-66622d90ac56' ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
w3wp.exe (0x1B88)           SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring                  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Parent No    ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
w3wp.exe (0x1B88)           SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication       STS Call Claims Windows: Successfully requested sign-in claim identity for user 'ADVENTUREWORKS\Administrator'. ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
w3wp.exe (0x1B88)           SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring                  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Execution Time=3.7721274631273    ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   Topology                    Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 206293 Ensure: False, HashCode: 51726067, Id: 1ed98212-4998-4229-a889-e8b6895a3db0, Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipel... ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   Topology                    ...ine(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputT...  ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   Topology                    ...oProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Execut...  ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   Topology                    ...ionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()     ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Server       Workflow Services           Unexpected retrieval of property on WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy:    ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4


PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowEndpointNotFoundException: Unable to connect to the remote service at http://sharepoint01.com:12291/SharePoint/. See InnerException for more details. Client ActivityId : ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 208.73.211.230:12291     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.... ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  ...Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ScopeManager.Get()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServerPairingContext.RegisterFarm()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessReco...  ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4



PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  ...rd() ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL ce9ff6bc-b517-4eb7-9fb1-ea0197e2a3c4
PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x2430) SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell                  Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Register-SPWorkflowService. 33832a19-2b3a-0000-3c31-83333a2bcf01
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Can you make sure there is a site binding for Workflow Management Site on port 12291?

- To check, go onto the **server** where you have the workflow manager installed.
- Then open **IIS** and go to **Sites** and click **Workflow Management Site**.
- Then click "**Bindings...**" on the right hand-side under "**Actions**" and
  check if you have a binding there for port **12291**.

If you don't, then add one like this:

- type: **HTTP**
- IP address: **All Unassigned**
- Port: **12291**
- Host name: ***[leave it blank]***

Click **OK** and restart **IIS**.

---

Now try registering your site collection with the Workflow manager Farm again.

Comment: Great respect to You! :) Awesome, You saved my evening! :)  + I also can add that we can enable HTTP using this code:   $config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.AllowMetaDataOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are using the right port. it can either be 12991 or 12291.

Check carefully in the IIS server.

Comment: 12290 for https and 12291 for http

Answer (score 0):

do you have SharePoint Developer tools Preview for VS 12 installed on the server, if yes? you have to uninstall it, reboot it and run the register command again.
[SharePoint 2013 Workflow Manager error when I register workflow service](http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/SharePoint_2013_Workflow_Manager_error_when_I_register_workflow/?TopicId=65294&Posts=11)

Also make sure ports are not blocked by firewall.
and try to browse the endpoint URI url in the browser.

Comment: "do you have SharePoint Developer tools Preview for VS 12 installed on the server" Do you have a picture to show it? I might understand better.

Comment: "endpoint URI url"? What do you mean? Concrete example?

Comment: i dont have installed that on any serve, so i cant give you the screen print, One thing which I noticed from your Screen Shot that you have the Visual Studio on the server...so chances are you have this tool....Endpoint URI means which have the port number i.e 12990 or something like this.

Comment: Go to Control Panel > Uninstall a program
Select Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 - Preview 2 - ENU
Click on Change to uninstall it. The setup program should launch.
Click on Uninstall to remove the Office Developer Tools.

Comment: I dont have Microsoft Office Developer Tools installed in my computer. I use Visual Studio 2013 and VS 2012.................. The Endpoint URI 12990 and 12991 is working perfectly according to Windows firewll. Please look at the new uploaded picture above.